# Why am I getting this error? UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `devicefarm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to ListProjects in AWS Device Farm.

Here's my code:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region:'us-east-1' });
const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: '***' });
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
    
const devicefarm = new AWS.DeviceFarm();
    
async function run() {
  let projects = await devicefarm.listProjects().promise();
  console.log(projects);
}
    
run();
```

I'm getting this error:

> UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `devicefarm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'.`
> This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/rande.html, Device Farm is only available in `us-west-2`?

Changing `AWS.config.update({ region:'us-east-1' });` to `AWS.config.update({ region:'us-west-2' });` worked:

Working code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region:'us-west-2' });
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: '***' });
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

var devicefarm = new AWS.DeviceFarm();

async function run() {
    let projects = await devicefarm.listProjects().promise();
    console.log(projects);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and realised that uploads were failing because my internet connection was too slow to resolve the DNS of bucket URL. However, slow connection is not the only reason for this error -- network/server/service/region/data center outage could also be the possible root cause.

AWS provides a dashboard to get health reports of the services offered and the same is available at [this link](https://status.aws.amazon.com/). API to access the services' health is also available.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, I have resolved following way

**Error:**

Region: '`Asia Pacific (Mumbai) ap-south-1`' which I choose

**Solution:**

In region instead of writing the entire name, you should only mention the region code

Region: `ap-south-1`

Comment: Me too!  This was my solution.  How easy was that?  Thx.  jb

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and checked all the github issues as well as SO answers, not much help.

If you are also in the `corporate` environment as I am and get this error *locally*, it is quite possible because you did not have the **proxy** setup in the SDK.

```js
import HttpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    credentials,
    httpOptions: { agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.https_proxy) },
  });
```

Normally the code might work in your ec2/lambda as they have vpc endpoint but locally you might need proxy in order to access the bucket url: `YourBucketName.s3.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 1):

Well for anyone still having this issue, I managed to solve it by changing the `endpoint` parameter passed in to the `AWS.config.update()` from an ARN string example `arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-<generated from AWS>:table/<tableName>` to the URL example `https://dynamodb.aws-region.amazonaws.com`, but replacing `aws-region` with your region in my case `ap-southeast-1`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.Summary.html

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I just change the origin in the .env file.

Previous value:-

**"Asia Pacific (Mumbai) ap-south-1"**

Corrected value:-

**"ap-south-1"**

Answer (score 0):

I just kept trying `amplify init` until it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to switch off my VPN.

Comment: same for me ...